# How do i force scucceed my codebuild? Even when there is a Error

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I want my codebuild to be success all the time.Please help me with what i should be adding in Envt Variables

```
  ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildRole.Arn
  Environment:
    Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
    Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0
    ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
    EnvironmentVariables: 
      - Name: CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE
        Type: PLAINTEXT
        Value: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${TargetAccountID}:role/${CodePipelineAssumeRoleName}'
      - Name: TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID
        Type: PLAINTEXT
        Value: !Ref TargetAccountID
```

Answer (score 1):

in your buildspec.yml set `CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING=1`

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html